# creating pandas dataframe with a function throwing 'df not defined' error

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a function as below to create a dataframe from a bigger dataframe

```
def prepare_data(cyl,typ):
global variable_name
global variable_name2
mask_bel1800 = (data_train_bel1800['Cycle'] == cyl) & (data_train_bel1800['Type'] == typ)
variable_name = ("DF{c}_{s}".format(c=cyl, s=typ))
variable_name = data_train_bel1800.loc[mask_bel1800, :]


mask = (data_train['Cycle'] == cyl) & (data_train['Type'] == typ)
variable_name2 = ("DF{c}_{s}_full".format(c=cyl, s=typ))
variable_name2 = data_train.loc[mask, :]

print('dataframe ' +'"DF'+str(cyl)+'_'+str(typ) +'"'+ " upto 1800 is ready")
print('dataframe ' +'"DF'+str(cyl)+'_'+str(typ)+'_full'+'"' " is ready")
```

When I put the statement `print(variable_name)` inside this function, the dataframe is printed. 
However, after i run this function & then I try to access the dataframe with `df.head()`, i get the error 'df is not defined'!!! what i am doing wrong?

Error i am getting is below
[image]

If I 'print' the dataframe directly, it prints (pic below)
[image]

I checked to make sure i have the right dataframe name by print just the variable "Variable name" and that is correct also[image: ![enter image description here]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbNX9.png)

Comment: this question does not seem complete... see if you can put more samples so we recreate the issue.

Comment: the df created depends on "cyl" and "typ". Since "cyl" and "typ" change almost always, i wanted the new df that is created to have the name of these values. So, i am assigning the "variable name" variable would be "DF9_1" if i pass cyl as 9 & typ as 1 (these values are used to create mask for the new df). Then  a df named "DF9_1" gets created. I am using the print statement bove only to print the name of the dataframe that has been created. However, when i try to access thes dataframe that is actually created, "DF9_1" for example, i get the error "NameError: name 'DF9_1' is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your function is missing the `return` statement so it returns `None`. You also need to assign the return value of a function to a variable to be able to use it later. For example:

```py
def prepare_data(data, cyl, typ):
    mask = (data['Cyl'] == cyl) & (data['Typ'] == typ)
    prepared = data.loc[mask, :]
    print(f'Dataframe {cyl}_{typ}_full created.')
    return prepared
```

Now you will be able to call the function and print the result like this:

```py
df = prepare_data(data_train, cyl, typ)
print(df)
```

The function uses `data_train`, `cyl` and `typ` as the input and returns `prepared`. That means that `df` outside the function is now what `prepared` was inside the function.

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working."return" statement prints the dataframe as well. I just need the function to create the dataframe & let me knwo the names of the dataframe so that i can work with them later

Comment: `return` does not print the dataframe. Return says what the output of the function is. If you are using ipython or jupyter notebooks (it looks like you are), then running a cell like `prepare_data(data_train, cyl, typ)` will indeed print the dataframe. That is a feature of the notebooks. But running a cell like `df = prepare_data(data_train, cyl, typ)` will not print the dataframe. Instead, it will take the dataframe and give it a label `df` which you can use to refer to the dataframe.

Comment: Correct. I tried it again & df was indeed the dataframe. However, in my function, i am creating 2 dataframes. df will be the first dataframe. How do i pass the second dataframe to a variable like this?

Comment: If you simply want to create another dataframe using the same function with different arguments, you should just call the function again `df2 = prepare_data(data_train, cyl2, typ2)`.
A function can return pretty much anything. If you change the line to `return (df1, df2)`, it will return a tuple of `df1` and `df2` (assuming that df1 and df2 exist within the scope of the function!). You can then even unpack the tuple like this: `df1, df2 = prepare_data(data_train, cyl, typ)`.