# dataframe results changes to zero after adding return

Tags: pandas

I am trying to pass "buy_list" in the code below to df . This is a small section of the code when the full code is executed I get the results of a back test results linked image.
[initial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnGsC.png)

```
    replacement_stocks = portfolio_size - len(kept_positions)
buy_list = ranking_table.loc[
    ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]

new_portfolio = pd.concat(
    (buy_list, 
     ranking_table.loc[ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)])
)
```

When I define df as in below I get df not defined error

```
    replacement_stocks = portfolio_size - len(kept_positions)
buy_list = ranking_table.loc[
    ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]

new_portfolio = pd.concat(
    (buy_list, 
     ranking_table.loc[ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)])
)
df1 = buy_list # ceate df1 with buy_list
df2 = ranking_table.loc[
    ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]# create df2 with buy_list
```

I tried the solution in the link below
[Similar error with suggested fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769724/creating-pandas-dataframe-with-a-function-throwing-df-not-defined-error)

Following this I still get df not defined error and the output of my back test changes to 0% in all the month which previously had actual % change negative and positive

```
    replacement_stocks = portfolio_size - len(kept_positions)
buy_list = ranking_table.loc[
    ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]

new_portfolio = pd.concat(
    (buy_list, 
     ranking_table.loc[ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)])
)
return buy_list

df2 = ranking_table.loc[
    ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]
```

`print(df2)`

This is what I now end up with
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ngUY.png)

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how I can fix this. 
Thanks,
Last1

Below is the full code as requested, it's from a book am working through, Trading Evolved by Andreas Clenow.

Thanks again.

```
%matplotlib inline

import zipline
from zipline.api import order_target_percent, symbol,  \
    set_commission, set_slippage, schedule_function, \
    date_rules, time_rules, attach_pipeline, pipeline_output
from pandas import Timestamp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyfolio as pf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  
from scipy import stats  
from zipline.finance.commission import PerDollar
from zipline.finance.slippage import VolumeShareSlippage, FixedSlippage
from zipline_norgatedata.pipelines import NorgateDataIndexConstituent
from zipline.pipeline import Pipeline


"""
Model Settings
"""
intial_portfolio = 100000
momentum_window1 = 125
momentum_window2 = 125
minimum_momentum = 40
portfolio_size = 30
vola_window = 20

# Trend filter settings
enable_trend_filter = True 
trend_filter_symbol = '$SPXTR'
trend_filter_window = 200

"""
Commission and Slippage Settings
"""
enable_commission = True
commission_pct = 0.001
enable_slippage = True 
slippage_volume_limit = 0.025
slippage_impact = 0.05

"""
Helper functions.
"""

def momentum_score(ts):
    """
    Input:  Price time series.
    Output: Annualized exponential regression slope, 
            multiplied by the R2
    """
    # Make a list of consecutive numbers
    x = np.arange(len(ts)) 
    # Get logs
    log_ts = np.log(ts) 
    # Calculate regression values
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, log_ts)
    # Annualize percent
    annualized_slope = (np.power(np.exp(slope), 252) - 1) * 100
    #Adjust for fitness
    score = annualized_slope * (r_value ** 2)
    return score

def volatility(ts):
    return ts.pct_change().rolling(vola_window).std().iloc[-1]

"""
Initialization and trading logic
"""

def make_pipeline():
   indexconstituent = NorgateDataIndexConstituent('$SPX')
   return Pipeline(
       columns={
            'NorgateDataIndexConstituent':indexconstituent},
       screen = indexconstituent)

def initialize(context):

    attach_pipeline(make_pipeline(), 'norgatedata_pipeline', chunks=9999,eager=True)

    # Set commission and slippage.
    if enable_commission:
        comm_model = PerDollar(cost=commission_pct)
    else:
        comm_model = PerDollar(cost=0.0)
    set_commission(comm_model)

    if enable_slippage:
        slippage_model=VolumeShareSlippage(volume_limit=slippage_volume_limit, price_impact=slippage_impact)
        set_slippage(slippage_model)
    else:
        slippage_model=FixedSlippage(spread=0.0)        

    # Used only for progress output.
    context.last_month = intial_portfolio

    # Store index membership
    #context.index_members = pd.read_csv('../data/index_members/sp500.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

    #Schedule rebalance monthly.
    schedule_function(
        func=rebalance,
        date_rule=date_rules.month_start(),
        time_rule=time_rules.market_open()
    )

def output_progress(context):
    """
    Output some performance numbers during backtest run
    """

    # Get today's date
    today = zipline.api.get_datetime().date()

    # Calculate percent difference since last month
    perf_pct = (context.portfolio.portfolio_value / context.last_month) - 1

    # Print performance, format as percent with two decimals.
    print("{} - Last Month Result: {:.2%}".format(today, perf_pct))

    # Remember today's portfolio value for next month's calculation
    context.last_month = context.portfolio.portfolio_value


def rebalance(context, data):
    # Write some progress output during the backtest
    output_progress(context)
    context.pipeline_data = pipeline_output('norgatedata_pipeline')

    todays_universe = context.pipeline_data.index


    # Check how long history window we need.
    hist_window = max(momentum_window1,
                      momentum_window2) 

    # Get historical data
    hist = data.history(todays_universe, "close", hist_window, "1d")

    # Slice the history to match the two chosen time frames.
    momentum_hist1 = hist[(-1 * momentum_window1):]
    momentum_hist2 = hist[(-1 * momentum_window2):]

    # Calculate momentum values for the two time frames.
    momentum_list1 = momentum_hist1.apply(momentum_score)  
    momentum_list2 = momentum_hist2.apply(momentum_score) 

    # Now let's put the two momentum values together, and calculate mean.
    momentum_concat = pd.concat((momentum_list1, momentum_list2))
    mom_by_row = momentum_concat.groupby(momentum_concat.index)
    mom_means = mom_by_row.mean()

    # Sort by momentum value.
    ranking_table = mom_means.sort_values(ascending=False)



    """
    Sell Logic

    First we check if any existing position should be sold.
    * Sell if stock is no longer part of index.
    * Sell if stock has too low momentum value.
    """
    kept_positions = list(context.portfolio.positions.keys())
    for security in context.portfolio.positions:
        if (security not in todays_universe):
            order_target_percent(security, 0.0)
            kept_positions.remove(security)      
        elif ranking_table[security] < minimum_momentum:
            order_target_percent(security, 0.0)
            kept_positions.remove(security)         

    """
    Trend Filter Section
    """
    if enable_trend_filter:
        ind_hist = data.history(
            symbol(trend_filter_symbol), 
            'close', 
            trend_filter_window, 
            '1d'
        )

        trend_filter = ind_hist.iloc[-1] > ind_hist.mean()    
        if trend_filter == False:
            return    

    """
    Stock Selection Logic

    Check how many stocks we are keeping from last month.
    Fill from top of ranking list, until we reach the
    desired total number of portfolio holdings.
    """
    replacement_stocks = portfolio_size - len(kept_positions)
    buy_list = ranking_table.loc[
        ~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacement_stocks]

    new_portfolio = pd.concat(
        (buy_list, 
         ranking_table.loc[ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)])
    )









    """
    Calculate inverse volatility for stocks, 
    and make target position weights.
    """
    vola_table = hist[new_portfolio.index].apply(volatility)
    inv_vola_table = 1 / vola_table 
    sum_inv_vola = np.sum(inv_vola_table)         
    vola_target_weights = inv_vola_table / sum_inv_vola

    for security, rank in new_portfolio.iteritems():
        weight = vola_target_weights[security]
        if security in kept_positions:
            order_target_percent(security, weight)
        else:
            if ranking_table[security] > minimum_momentum:
                order_target_percent(security, weight)

def analyze(context, perf):

    perf['max'] = perf.portfolio_value.cummax()
    perf['dd'] = (perf.portfolio_value / perf['max']) - 1
    maxdd = perf['dd'].min()

    ann_ret = (np.power((perf.portfolio_value.iloc[-1] / perf.portfolio_value.iloc[0]),(252 / len(perf)))) - 1

    print("Annualized Return: {:.2%} Max Drawdown: {:.2%}".format(ann_ret, maxdd))

    return   

start_date = Timestamp('2015-01-01',tz='UTC')
end_date = Timestamp('2020-03-14',tz='UTC')

perf = zipline.run_algorithm(
    start=start_date, end=end_date, 
    initialize=initialize, 
    analyze=analyze, 
    capital_base=intial_portfolio,  
    data_frequency = 'daily', 
    bundle='norgatedata-sp500' )
```

Comment: What is your full code? Where do you define the `ranking_table` variable?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 the full code has been added to the post.

Comment: Thanks @Last1, that is helpful. Is the "Sell Logic", "Trend Filter Section" and "Stock Selection Logic" actually inside your `rebalance` function or is that a copypasta error and they are in the global scope? Looks like you define your `ranking_table` variable inside that function, thus once you exit that function, that variable will no longer exist so if you try to reference it outside the scope of that function it will produce a `NameError`.

Comment: @Phillyclause89 Thanks for looking at this for me. Yes the sell logic is inside "rebalance" and no it is not a copy and paste error. The book is geared at beginners like me a great introduction to Python the author opted for simplicity for that reason. Is there a way to get at the "ranking_list" or even "ranking_table" or even the higher level dataframe. I can access everything in the results level but hoping to actually get in a bit higher. I tried use "nuy_list.to_csv" but that resulted in the output stopping after the first go round.

Comment: Yeah this code uses a lot of libs that I haven't used before and I don't think I fully understand what exactly your end goal is here, but if you want those dfs after you exit your function you could make two lists in the outer scope and append the dfs to them from inside the function. functions can access modify variables defined in the outer scope, but the outer scope can't do the opposite. here is a [pasetebin](https://pastebin.com/jZXbTzPU) of a truncated version of your code to show what i'm talking about.

Comment: I like to think you fixed your own problem. I just help nudge you in the right direction.  I suggest you write up and post an answer to your own question here. I'll toss you an upvote if it looks nice (or suggest an edit if I see something wrong) then you'll be a few more upvotes away from the Self-Learner badge ;)